# Is there another means of getting icons without using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have HTML codes I did with pure html and CSS, I need to add icons like 'home' to it but I don't know how to, I don't know how to use bootstrap so please tell me how I can get icons with HTML or something else

Comment: Try fontawesome or any other icon font on the internet, include the font and the css and you're good to go

Comment: you can try using fontawesome as SVG code for reducing HTTP requests

Comment: Not sure if you're asking how to install Boostrap Icons or you're asking for alternative libraries but both questions would really be out of the scope of this site, which aims to be a collaborative knowledge-base.

Comment: If you need an icon for home please try this one: `<svg width='24'  viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
<path d='M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3l-10-9-10 9h3v8z'></path>
<path d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'></path>
</svg>`  In this example the width="24" but you can change it to what you need. You can also add a `fill` attribute for color or you can set the value for `fill` in css. For more svg icons please take a look at the [Google's svg icons](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/VKoqqG?editors=1111)

Answer (score -1):

the best way, in my opinion, is to get any icons you want as SVG code, for example, you can download fontawesome icons as SVG

and then minify them through this website https://vecta.io/nano

after that add the minified SVG code to HTML and add some styling

this way you reduced HTTP requests and at the same time didn't lose quality

ps: you have to figure the best setting of [viewBox="0 0 384 512"] attribute values because if your SVG code doesn't have the right values of viewBox attribute then you can't scale your SVG through CSS

```css
.iconsWrapper {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.icon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.stack {
    fill: #F48024;
}
```

```html
<span class="iconsWrapper">
  <svg class="stack icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512" xmlns:v="https://vecta.io/nano">
      <path d="M290.7 311L95 269.7 86.8 309l195.7 41zm51-87L188.2 95.7l-25.5 30.8 153.5 128.3zm-31.2 39.7L129.2 179l-16.7 36.5L293.7 300zM262 32l-32 24 119.3 160.3 32-24zm20.5 328h-200v39.7h200zm39.7 80H42.7V320h-40v160h359.5V320h-40z" />
  </svg>
</span>
```